# How to disable widget all page in a website?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple code in functions.php in wordpress theme

```
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'disable_all_widgets' );

function disable_all_widgets( $sidebars_widgets ) {
    if ((is_single() || is_home() || is_front_page()) && have_posts())
        $sidebars_widgets = array( false );
    return $sidebars_widgets;
}
```

When I in Home page is result OK, but when I click on menu other menu home page is result show all widget, how to disable all widget all pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable all widgets in all pages:

```
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'disable_all_widgets' );

function disable_all_widgets( $sidebars_widgets ) {
    return array( false );
}
```

Simply don't do the check.